# Como faço um DropDownList ligado com uma propriedade do model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho minha classe:

```
public class Topico
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
}
```

e minha classe SubTopico

```
public class SubTopico
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Topico Topico { get; set; }
    public int? TopicoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
}
```

No meu controller tenho:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Topico = new SelectList(db.Topicoes, "Id", "Nome");
    return View();
}
```

e na minha view tenho meu `DropDownList`

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Topico",string.Empty)
```

Até aí ele carrega todos os tópicos, etc.

Mas não consigo fazer um Bind nele ao salvar.
Na minha action para Salvar

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Topico,Nome,Observacao")] SubTopico subtopico)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        subtopico.TopicoId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["Topico"]);
        db.SubTopicoes.Add(subtopico);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(subtopico);
}
```

Ele não vem o Id do Tópico, até por que a classe está null.
Então eu capturo usando `Request.Params["Topico"];`

Como faço para vincular meu dropdownlist com a minha propriedade `public virtual Topico` que eu tenho na minha classe SubTopico

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do jeito que você fez, na primeira vez do questionamento, seria assim:

```cs
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Topico = new SelectList(db.Topicoes, "Id", "Nome");
    return View();
}
```

Na View:

```cs
@Html.DropDownList("TopicoId", ViewBag.Topico as SelectList)
```

ou

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TopicoId, ViewBag.Topico as SelectList)
```

Comment: Muito bom @user6026 resolveu meu erro!

Answer (score 5):

Use `@DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.DropDownList(model => model.TopicoId, ((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Topicos).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = option.Nome, 
    Value = option.Id.Value, 
    Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Id == (int)Model.TopicoId ?? 0)
}, "Selecione..."))
```

Assim você não precisa usar `Request.Params`, que não é exatamente seguro.

Neste caso do `POST`, `Topico` vai vir nulo mesmo. Ele é carregado na seleção de dados, como por exemplo se você detalhar o `Subtopico` usando

```
context.Subtopicos.Include(st => st.Topico).FirstOrDefault();
```

Por fim, você pode simplificar seu `Controller` para:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,TopicoId,Nome,Observacao")] SubTopico subtopico)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.SubTopicoes.Add(subtopico);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(subtopico);
}
```

Comment: Da um erro, ao Colocar esse código na View, no Select

Comment: Você alterou de `ViewBag.Topico` para `ViewBag.Topicos` no seu `Controller`?

Comment: Sim, eu alterei ViewBag.Topicos por Topico, é a mesma ViewBag do controller

Comment: Ok, eu preciso de mais detalhes do erro pra poder te ajudar. A mensagem completa me ajuda bastante.

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma simples que achei e consegui foi:

No meu controller, retornar uma lista:

```
ViewBag.Topicos = db.Topicoes.ToList();
```

E na minha View usar o DropDownlistFor da seguinte maneira.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TopicoId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Topicos,"Id","Nome","Selecione..."))
```

Answer (score 3):

Também é possível usar consulta SQL como fonte de dados para o DropDownList:

No Controller:

```
public ActionResult NomeDaAction() {
    ViewBag.DadosDropDown = (from c in db.Tabela select c.ColunaDaTabela).Distinct();
    Return View();
}
```

No View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CampoOndeArmazenar, new SelectList(ViewBag.DadosDropDown, "Coluna1DaTabela", "OutraColunaDaTabela"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "ClasseCSSdoDropDownList" })
```

Sendo que, no view, caso não queira atribuir uma classe do CSS pra caixa de seleção, basta retirar o comando htmlAttributes conforme abaixo:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CampoOndeArmazenar, new SelectList(ViewBag.DadosDropDown, "Coluna1DaTabela", "OutraColunaDaTabela"))
```